# when I try to install by npm it frezzes in this step exactly

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

i was triyng to install babel and webpack by npm in command line
but when i type npm install it frezzes in this step exactly

: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\staging-d144261d8cd07e07.lock

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the previous output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a lot of different causes for your error as there is not a lot of information from you. If you have the time, please try the following:

- Uninstall [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
- Delete the cache folder from C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming
- Delete the node/npm file from C:\Users\YourName
- Uninstall [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/index.html)
- Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/index.html)

After you did all of the steps, please try to npm install again.